# cakeplugin not found in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new in cakephp. I am getting the following error in my page.

```
Error: Class 'cakeplugin' not found 
File: C:\wamp\www\cakephp\app\Config\bootstrap.php  
Line: 27
Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\fatal_error.ctp
```

Comment: Not sure how you expect people to help you if you don't show any code. For a start it would be useful if you shared the code at line 27 that is causing the error. At a guess you are calling `cakeplugin` rather than `CakePlugin`.

Comment: Please give some code to identify the problem

Answer (score 2):

To load all plugins that you have added, put this in your config/bootstrap.php,  :

```
CakePlugin::loadAll();
```